# Is it possible to integrate RSA SecurID into a rails app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, authentication, securid

I have a fairly standard Ruby on Rails app. Is there any way to integrate RSA SecurID or RSA risk based authentication into the login process? Is this even possible?

Answer (score 0):

All enterprise-call two-factor authentication systems support Radius - a very useful authentication protocol.  If there is a Ruby Radius module, then I suggest you use that.  That would be the most standard standard.  LDAP might also be an option.

If you are not yet wed to a two-factor solution, you might consider our solution, which has a Ruby module (LGPL licensed too) and it works with our open-source community edition.  The API packages are here: http://www.wikidsystems.com/downloads/network-clients.